# .done() jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im using the below code for a ajax call

```
var getRequest = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: Url,
    async: false,
    dataType: "text",
    complete: function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
```

the request is getting complete and data is also withdrawn after the data is recieved the following:

```
getRequest.done(function (dataDb) {
    if (dataDb) {
        alert('dataDb: ' + dataDb);

    }
});

getRequest.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    alert('data error within getUsersRequest ' + textStatus + ' : ' + error);
});
```

I'm recieving a error that `getRequest.done(function(dataDb)` or `getRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error)` is not a function.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Probably your are using an older one.

Comment: ajax is meant for asynchronous ops. Your setting `async: false` defies it. Bad design.

Comment: async:false is kept for coding reasons. Im using jquery 1.10.1

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().**

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `JQuery` version is too old.

You can use `success` if you are not willing to upgrade the latest version of `JQuery`.

```
success: function(dataDb) {

    }
```

Comment: you need to put `success` inside the `$.ajax({..})`

Answer (score 0):

`success` only fires if the AJAX call is successful from back end, i.e. it returns a `HTTP 200` status as response. if any error fires if it fails and complete when the request finishes, regardless of success.

In `jQuery 1.8` on the `jqXHR` object (returned by `$.ajax`) success is being replaced with the done, error with fail and complete with always.

However you should still be able to initialise the `AJAX request` with the current syntax. So these do similar things:

```
// set success action before making the request
$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  success: function(){
    alert('AJAX successful');
  }
});

// set success action just after starting the request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "..." )
  .done(function() { alert("success"); });
```

**Last:** you need to use `.success` rather then using `.done`

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `.success`.

```
var getRequest = $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : Url,
                async: false,
                dataType: "text",
                complete: function(){
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }).success(function(dataDb){   
                if(dataDb) {
                    alert('dataDb: '+ dataDb);

                } 
            });
```